# Get rid from the text indentation

Tags: css, padding, indentation

How could I get rid from the text indentation in my case?

html:

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="promptTitle">
    Module Name
  </div>

  <div class="drawRegion">

  </div>

  <div class="nameTitle">
    Module Name
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mainContainer {
  border: 1px darkgray solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.promptTitle {
  color: #b8b8b8;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.drawRegion {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nameTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/561/

problem on screenshot:

[image]

My problem is that the second line of text `Module Name` is displayed with an indentation. I would expect to not have the indentation.

That is because the first `Module Name` indented `70px` from left, while the second `Module Name` indented `50px` from left due to the element with `class="drawRegion"` and `20px` due to its own left padding. So, in total both first and second `Module Name` should indent `70px`. And hence both should be placed with the same indentation, but this is not the case.

So, what am I missing here or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: .drawRegion + padding are in the way, reset and/or remove them. https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/563/ https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/565/

Comment: @G-Cyr, this will remove the indentation totally. I want to remove the extra indentation only.

Comment: it's white space between inline-block element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the spacing between the drawRegion & nameTitle inline-block divs.

```css
.mainContainer {
  border: 1px darkgray solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.promptTitle {
  color: #b8b8b8;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.drawRegion {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nameTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="promptTitle">Module Name</div>
  <div class="drawRegion"></div><div class="nameTitle">Module Name</div>
</div>
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/5385381) for a good explanation of white space between inline & inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in making the `nameTitle` as `inline-block` as you display the elements as *blocks*.

Therefore, keep the same CSS styles for the first and the last element.

```
.nameTitle {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: check his code well, there is another element before (actually empty but with a width), so he don't need to make it block

Comment: @TemaniAfif That one can be also `block`.

Comment: no, because there is an element before and both should be on the same line